# How to count the number of numbers generated in the Collatz Conjecture AND display all the values?

Tags: python, math, sequence

This is what I have so far. It basically generate the arithmetic sequence for the Collatz Conjecture. What I need now is for it count the number of values in that arithmetic sequence in real time when the code is being processed.

```
n = 31415

print(n)
while n > 1:
    if n % 2 == 0 :
        n = n//2
        print (n)
    else:
        n = 3*n+1
        print (n)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to add a counter variable that increment each time a loop is made

```
n = 31415
counter = 0
print(n)
while n > 1:
   if n % 2 == 0 :
      n = n//2
      print (n)
   else:
      n = 3*n+1
      print (n)
   counter += 1
   print(counter)
```

Comment: Please mark it as resolved

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar. I wanted the user entered number to display in the results and be counted. I also wanted the user to be able to enter the number 1. This is what I came up with.

```
def collatz(num):
    count = 0         
    print (num)         #Returns user entered value in the result
    count = count + 1   #Counts the user entered value.
    while True:
        if (num % 2) == 0:  #Evaluates if num is even number
            num = num // 2  #Performs calc for even number and assigns to num
            print(num)
        elif num % 2 == 1:    #Evaluates if num is odd number
            num = 3 * num + 1 #Performs calc for odd number and assigns to num
            print(num)
        count = count + 1   #Adds one to the count
        if num == 1:        #Evalutes if num is = to 1.
           print('It took', count,'iterations to complete the sequence.') 
           sys.exit()
```